# Отступ от верхнего края экрана при переходе по якорям

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Задача состоит в следующем. На сайте вверху фиксированный блок определенной высоты. На страницах есть якоря. При переходе по якорной ссылке с одной страницы на другую, страница открывается как и положено, т.е якорь оказывается у верхнего края окна. И тем самым прячется под фиксированным блоком. Подобные варианты, например с padding+margin, :before или :after, не подходят, потому как по умолчанию у этих якорей никаких отступов быть не должно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли с помощью javascript решить задачу таким образом, чтобы исключительно при переходе по якорным ссылкам страница загружалась с определенным отступом от верхнего края экрана? Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то названия якоря на всех этих страницах одинаковые, а вот отступы будут разные. Как вариант к примеру примеру задавай некий data-marginTop:"30" для этого этого блока, потом заносить в переменную, и менять его значение на некую разницу которая тебе нужна.

Comment: Ну тогда присваивай всем этим перекрывающим блокам один и тот же класс. Например decor-marginTop узнавай его высоту (вместе с отступами) которая будет меняться в зависимости от контента который в нём содержаться в той или иной странице, и отнимай от прокрутки эту величину